# ObjectBox: Get objects with specific relations

Tags: java, android, objectbox

Expect the two entities `Movie` and `Genre`:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

@Id
private long id;
private String name;
private ToMany<Genre> genres;

[...]
}

@Entity
public class Genre {

@Id
private long id;
private String name;

[...]
}
```

We all know how to create a relation and save it:

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.setTitle("Star Wars");
movie.getGenres().add(new Genre("Sci-Fi");
box.put(movie);
```

but is there a possibility to query all `Movie`-objects with a specific `Genre`? Like

```
Box<Movie> box = boxStore.boxFor(Movie.class);

Query query = box.query()
  .equal(Genre_.name, "Sci-Fi") // note that I want to query the Movie-Box with Genre-properties
  .build();
List movies = query.find();
```

My goal is to find all movies with a specific genre in a simple way. Does anyone know how to do it or do I have to query all movies and filter the result on my own? Or do I have to adapt my entities in another way?

**Update:**
I prepared the correct marked answer below to a working example:

```
    final Genre genreSciFi = genreBox.query().equal(Genre_.name, "Sci-Fi").build().findFirst();

    List<Movie> filteredMovies = movieBox.query().filter(new QueryFilter<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public boolean keep(@NonNull Movie entity) {
            return entity.getGenres().contains(genreSciFi);
        }
    }).build().find();
```

To make the `contains`-Method work correctly, override `equals`-Method in your `Genre`-Entity:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Genre && ((Genre) obj).getId() == id && ((Genre) obj).getName().equals(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this part of the API is not exposed in Java yet. We want to refactor the Query API very soon.

Until this is ready, you can workaround using [query filtering](http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/query/QueryBuilder.html#filter-io.objectbox.query.QueryFilter-). Example using Java/Kotlin-ish code for brevity:

```
Query query = movieBox.query().filter(movie -> { 
    return genres.contains(genre -> {
        return "Sci-Fi".equals(genre.getName())
    }
}).build()
```

(Will make it similar in Java with the next update.)

Comment: I updated my question by a working example based on your hint! Thanks for your answer and for the nice talk on the last droidcon ;-)